# Fabric plugin for Android Studio is not showing the Distribution Screen

Tags: android-studio, google-fabric

I'm trying upload an apk to the beta test in fabric but no luck till now, I'm following the [official documentation](https://docs.fabric.io/android/beta/beta-walkthrough.html) but I can't see the "Distribution screen" section, why?

I just downloaded the last version of the plugin and the only option is to create a new app, I won't create a new one due I already have the crashlytics configured in my app.

I wanna upload my not production apk to the beta test like the tutorial shows.

[image]

Comment: Please don't add rants to your posts. They add no value what so ever to the post or the site, and is highly likely to be removed (or worse if the entire post is one). If you want to rant, please do so elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

1. Click the left-top Button
2. Create an app, or select an app.

and then off you go!

1:

[image: Click the left-top Button]

2:

[image]

Comment: "I won't create a new one due I already have the crashlytics configured in my app"

Comment: In that case you can select you app in step 2